# laoding custom javascript in Angular

Tags: angular

I try to load an external javascript file in Angular. But keep getting the error:
'ERROR ReferenceError: offerNotification is not defined'.
I followed the tutorial on youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VR-ebRiruB4

Javascript file (notifications.js):

```
function() showNotification(){ console.log("show notification")}
```

angular.json (under build/scripts and build/assets)

```
"scripts": [
          "src/assets/js/notifications.js"           
        ]

""assets": [
          "src/favicon.ico",
          "src/assets",
          "src/service-worker.js",
          "src/assets/js/notifications.js"              
        ]
```

app.component.ts

```
declare const showNotification;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss',
})


export class AppComponent {
  title = 'AngularConnowPocApp';
  callfun(){
    showNotification();
  }
}
```

app.component.html

```
<div class="container">
  <button (click)='callfun()'>show notification</button>
</div>
```

}

Comment: did you declare the function in app.component.ts?
declare const showNotification: any;

Comment: What's offerNotification() ? if it is a function shows the code.

Comment: https://www.truecodex.com/course/angular-6/how-to-use-external-js-files-and-javascript-code-in-angular try this

Comment: did you try to debug the code? if so check callfun() is getting execute by putting break point on it.

Comment: My excuses, I didn't place the correct code.  I adjusted it just now.

Comment: I correct the declared the 'showNotification' in my code and replaced the offerNotification().

Comment: This should work. In dev mode, just by putting a reference to the file in scripts array should do the trick (no need to reference it in the assets array in dev mode)

Comment: Thx everyone for the support. I got it working in a new angular project I created. But somehow in my PWA project it still doesn't work..